# TFS 2010 Personal Branch

Tags: tfs

> In TFS, if you want to create a personal branch to try out an idea you
>   have, you will have to create a branch on the TFS server – even if no
>   one else needs access to your code. And when you create this branch,
>   every single file in your project will be duplicated – even if your
>   branch has very few changes compared to the original one. Now you’re
>   using twice the amount of disk space both on the server and locally!

Is this true, and one of the downsides of a non-distributed VCS?

Answer (score 5):

Both statements are wrong. (Where did you read this?)

> In TFS, if you want to create a personal branch to try out an idea you have, you will have to create a branch on the TFS server

No you don't always need a branch if you're just "trying out an idea". Of course it depends on what you want to do. Saving your work on the server to secure it against drive crashes is what shelvesets are for in TFS (other VCSs may not provide anything similar, which is why you need to create a branch for every idea there). You can even share your code with others without actually checking it in using shelvesets. Even a simple kind of versioning can be done by including the timestamp in the names of the shelvesets, but this is tedious, probably more so than creating a branch ;) Building your code on the server is another thing you can do with shelvesets.

You should read up on when to use shelvesets over changesets on MSDN (there is an article somewhere) to decide whether you need a new branch.

> Now you’re using twice the amount of disk space both on the server and locally!

The copying of the code only happens virtually. The SQL Server behind the TFS Server will *not* use up twice the space, unless every file actually changes on either one of these branches. Until then, both files on the two branches will "point" to the exact same memory on the SQL Server. If you need to work on both branches simultaneously and map them into your workspace, then of course you need twice the amount of space locally. Both is true for any VCS I am aware of, so this is not a TFS-specific issue.

Comment: Indeed. In addition if you do create a branch, in TFS 2010 or above, this is created on the server (using pointers as you mentioned) so you only need to get the files / projects you want to modify. This would take up significantly less space than a DVCS which creates the entire repository locally. There are many advantages to DVCS, but local disk space isn't one of them